# Using parameter to create template that will show html code

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure that after using it should create html code with headers and content. I have this pattern:

```html
    <h2>First Column</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ul>
</div>


    <h2>Second Column</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ul>
</div>


    <h2>Third Column</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ul>
```

In my procedure I declare 2 parameters:
@header - that I want use in First Column, Second Column, Third Column
@content - that I want use in First item, Second Item, Third Item

After declaration I need help to set those 2 parameters to get data from table.
All rows from, header should be main columns in html(First Column etc) and content 1, content 2 should be placed in the list (First item etc).
I have one table:

| header | Content1 | Content2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row1 | row1 |
| Second | row2 | row2 |
| Third | row3 | row3 |

I know it's a lot of information and maybe not everything is clear but let me know if I should add something.
Thank you

Comment: Some meaningful, and consumable, sample data, and expected results, along with your attempt (you say you have a procedure, but the definition is missing from your question) will greatly help us help you. Or are you saying that you need to consume said HTML and turn it into the table you you show at the end of your question?

Comment: @Larnu Hi thanks for fast response. sql table that I showed in the end is something that I have already. I need to use data from it (first column as header and other columns as content) to html. I just don't know how should I set those parameters to get html view like in the begining.

Comment: I really don't follow. The HTML you appear to want to make is purely based on the parameters, as far as I can see; the table has nothing do with anything.

Comment: If you're using T-SQL to generate html this is a code smell already. Your HTML templating should be done in the presentation layer (either service side or client side depending on your application architecture), but certainly not in your data layer. It may be worth taking a step back, and explaining the wider problem that you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the table has to do with anything here, if I am honest. Assuming that the parameters are coming in as a delimited string, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and then `FOR XML PATH`:

```sql
DECLARE @header nvarchar(4000) = N'First Column,Second Column,Third Column',
        @content nvarchar(4000) = 'First item,Second Item,Third Item';

SELECT (SELECT H.[value] AS h2,
               (SELECT C.[value] AS [li]
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@content,N',') C
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) AS ul
        FOR XML PATH('div'),TYPE)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@header,N',') H
FOR XML PATH('');
```

This gives the following HTML:

```html
<div>
  <h2>First Column</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Second Column</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Third Column</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lamu Yes it's something like that.
I was wondering if I could use the sql table data to fill the html list. To create a pattern of some kind, so that every time I use this procedure pointing to a choosen table, it will create an html list with data from the database table filled in.
But it's ok maybe it's not possible. Thank you for answer.

Comment: I didn't say it's not possible, @Azawar . But your table and the HTML you want have no relationship. You can't make the HTML you want from that table, because they are nothing alike.